# What is a pointer of a pointer?

Tags: pointers

I am a Computer Science student and my teacher gave me an assignment to describe pointers and pointers of pointers, that I understand that are objects that contain the memory address of another object/variable (As far as I understand, please correct me if I am wrong) but for some reason I could not find good information about pointers of pointers, I have no idea if they point to the pointer or the address of the pointer they are pointing to, and I get confused just thinking about it. But the teacher made an assignment out of it so I imagine it has some use.

If anyone can also provide an example as to why you would use a pointer of another pointer, it does not sound much useful to me. This is also my first question here haha, please correct me if I did anything wrong.

I'm trying to understand pointers and pointers

Answer (score -1):

You've already got the right start! A pointer is an object that stores the memory address of another value located in the memory. This value can be any data type, including other pointers. Now, a pointer to a pointer is simply a pointer that stores the memory address of another pointer, rather than a "regular" value.

When you have a pointer to a pointer, you have a variable that holds the memory address of a different pointer variable. If you were to follow this address, you'd find yourself at another memory address - the one stored in the second pointer.

Here's a little example in C:

```c
int x = 10;        // x is an integer
int *p = &x;       // p is a pointer to an integer
int **pp = &p;     // pp is a pointer to a pointer to an integer
```

In this code, `x` is an integer that stores the value `10`. `p` is a pointer to an integer, and we initialize it with the address of `x`, so it "points" to `x`. Finally, `pp` is a pointer to a pointer to an integer, and we initialize it with the address of `p`, so it "points" to `p`.

If we print these variables and their values, we might get something like this:

```c
printf("%d\n", x);   // prints: 10
printf("%p\n", p);   // prints: address of x
printf("%p\n", pp);  // prints: address of p
printf("%d\n", *p);  // prints: 10
printf("%p\n", *pp); // prints: address of x
printf("%d\n", **pp);// prints: 10
```

Now, why would you want to use a pointer to a pointer? One common use case is when you want to change a pointer inside a function.

In C, function arguments are passed by value, which means that changing an argument inside a function does not affect its original value outside the function. However, if you want a function to change the original pointer, you can pass a pointer to the pointer and then dereference it inside the function.

Here's an example:

```c
void changePointer(int **pp) {
    int y = 20;
    *pp = &y;
}

int main(void) {
    int x = 10;
    int *p = &x;
    printf("%d\n", *p); // prints: 10
    changePointer(&p);
    printf("%d\n", *p); // prints: 20
    return 0;
}
```

In this code, the `changePointer` function changes the pointer `p` to point to a different integer `y`. This change persists after the function call because we passed a pointer to `p`, not `p` itself.

I hope this helps! Feel free to ask if you have further questions.

Comment: This looks like obfuscated ChatGPT